# Question about canonical normalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Are there ever instances where it is more convenient or more physically meaningful to work in terms of fields which are **not** canonically normalized? Obviously, nothing 'measurable' should be affected, i.e. S-matrix elements, but by meaningful I mean some property or structure in the theory is elucidated.